# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was following an online tutorial and everything was going fine until I got to the part about routers. I actually deleted all my code and pasted the instructor's from github and still get this error. Folder structure and dependencies are the same. I have no idea how to being troubleshooting this when the app just breaks. The command line is not displaying this error, only the browser

> Recipes.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Form from "./components/Form";
import Recipes from "./components/Recipes";

const API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        recipes: []
    }
    getRecipe = async (e) => { 
        const recipeName = e.target.elements.recipeName.value;
        e.preventDefault();
        const api_call = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}&q=${recipeName}&count=10`);

        const data = await api_call.json();
        this.setState({ recipes: data.recipes });
        console.log(this.state.recipes);
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        const json = localStorage.getItem("recipes");
        const recipes = JSON.parse(json);
        this.setState({ recipes });
    }
    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        const recipes = JSON.stringify(this.state.recipes);
        localStorage.setItem("recipes", recipes);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title">Recipe Search</h1>
                </header>
                <Form getRecipe={this.getRecipe} />
                <Recipes recipes={this.state.recipes} />
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;}
```

```
{import React from 'react';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Recipes = props => (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        { props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
          return (
            <div key={recipe.title} className="col-md-4" style={{ marginBottom:"2rem" }}>
                <div className="recipes__box">
                  <img
                      className="recipe__box-img"
                      src={recipe.image_url}
                      alt={recipe.title}/>
                  <div className="recipe__text">
                      <h5 className="recipes__title">
                      { recipe.title.length < 20 ? `${recipe.title}` : `${recipe.title.substring(0, 25)}...` }
                      </h5>
                      <p className="recipes__subtitle">Publisher: <span>
                      { recipe.publisher }
                      </span></p>
                  </div>
                  <button className="recipe_buttons">
                      <Link to={{
                      pathname: `/recipe/${recipe.recipe_id}`,
                      state: { recipe: recipe.title }
                      }}>View Recipe</Link>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
         );
       })}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Recipes;
```

Comment: Add some `console.log()`, before your `this.setState()` and find out why it's setting `this.state.recipies` to something other than an array.

Comment: My guess is, your `componentDidMount` method, is generating a null value. Add some checks in there, to ensure `const recipes = JSON.parse(json);` returns a valid array. If it does, THEN set it, otherwise leave it as it's initialized empty value (`[]`)

Comment: @FrankerZ logging before setState was the key. I think I found out that I just had a request limit on the API

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line at your code , Apply a OR condition, When the first time when you come to your code  `localStorage.getItem("recipes")` value is null, So because of this it is showing you that you ' Cannot read property 'map' of null'

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
        const json = localStorage.getItem("recipes") || [];
        const recipes = JSON.parse(json);
        this.setState({ recipes });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to fix it, you can add truthy check before mapping on array

```
props.recipes && props.recipes.map
```

And below modified code slightly to not cause rerender due to new empty array reference as suggested by other answer

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const json = localStorage.getItem("recipes");
    const recipes = JSON.parse(json);
    recipes && this.setState({ recipes });
}
```

Comment: While this fixes the issue, it's nice to find out *why* it's happening

Comment: Actually: The initial render it should be `[]`. He initializes his state as `[]`. It's likely in his `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: Yeah possibly, i guess this will put additional check inside rhe component itself.

Comment: Yes @FrankerZ his initial value is [], but once the render run than componentDidMount will execute and the first time the value of localStorage.getItem("recipes") will be `null`. Here he is doing setState so again it will call the render method and this time the value is `null`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I think you need to pass down `state` instead of `this.state` in your render method.

```
render() {
  return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
         <h1 className="App-title">Recipe Search</h1>
       </header>
       <Form getRecipe={this.getRecipe} />
       <Recipes recipes={state.recipes} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Typically when using state within a class component, state is declared in the `constructor` since it is the first method that is called in the component class. This [article](https://daveceddia.com/where-initialize-state-react/) goes in more detail about where to declare state within the component but the gist of it is that your component should look something like this:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      recipes: [],
    };
  }

  getRecipe = async (e) => { 
    const recipeName = e.target.elements.recipeName.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}&q=${recipeName}&count=10`);

    const data = await api_call.json();
    this.setState({ recipes: data.recipes });
    console.log(this.state.recipes);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const json = localStorage.getItem("recipes");
    const recipes = JSON.parse(json);
    this.setState({ recipes });
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    const recipes = JSON.stringify(this.state.recipes);
    localStorage.setItem("recipes", recipes);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Recipe Search</h1>
        </header>
        <Form getRecipe={this.getRecipe} />
        <Recipes recipes={this.state.recipes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives to solve this problem, my solution is to check if the "json" from localStorage exists which is when it is neither null or undefined or empty string,...

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem("recipes");

  if(json){
    const recipes = JSON.parse(json);
    this.setState({ recipes });
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented out componentDidMount and ran console.log(data) before setState and received back an object with {error: "limit"}. I checked the foodforfork api docs and sure enough theres a limit of 50 requests per day for free.

I'm going to check tomorrow to see if it's back to normal. My next question may be how to return a message when this happens rather than just break the app.

Thanks to all! I will mark as answered if it works tomorrow

Edit: just confirming that the problem was due to the API limit. Everything works as it should now.